# CSS Transforms property not working on dynamically injected html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transforms

I am trying to do text reveal animation on a dynamically injected h1 element which has text wrapped inside span element, but trying to animate with translate property doesn't seem to work. I've added `window.getComputedStyle()` to recalculate the styles before adding the transform: translate property to get the transform property working but still no luck. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!!

Here's the code!

```js
var textDiv = document.querySelector('.text');
textDiv.innerHTML = '<h1><span>Reveal</span></h1>';

var spanText = document.querySelector('span');
spanText.classList.add('show');
window.getComputedStyle(spanText).getPropertyValue('transform');

spanText.style.transform = 'translateY(100%)';
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #bedcff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  padding: 100px 20px 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 span {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
          transform: translateY(0%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  transition: transform 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: inline-block to span

Comment: Hi, you are adding a class 'show' but I can't see it in the given CSS.

Comment: Don't think you need the show class specifically, @TemaniAfit comment, setting span as inline-block seems to work.

Comment: @AHaworth Oh yes, I just pasted the css from the wrong file here. 'show' class adds the translateY(0%) property. Didn't know css- transforms doesn't work on inline elements. Man I should've asked this earlier. I just wasted hours fiddling with this. Thanks so much for the help!!